# How to print each character from a string?

Tags: java

Is there a way to read a single character at a time from the input and process it, without tokenizing the vocabulary?

Answer (score 12):

The toCharArray() function on Strings might be useful here.

```
for(char c : s.toCharArray())
     System.out.println(c);
```

And to print only the lowercase ones in the string- Thanks @fge

```
for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
        System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Yup, and then use `Character.toLowerCase()` to print the lowercase version of the character.

Comment: The user does not want to print chars to lower case...it only wants the lower case chars printed. I updated this response to do that ...waiting for approval.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) from [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which reads one `char` at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava's [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) to extract lower case letters from your string, then use [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) to put each character on a new line.

You can do all this in a single line of code as shown below:

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on('\n').join(Lists.charactersOf(CharMatcher.JAVA_LOWER_CASE.retainFrom(s))));
```